# How to interpret the plot of a function of a complex variable?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, graphing-functions

I know what a complex number is: $a+bi$. But I have seen these functions that make no sense to me, something such as this:
$$f(z)=z^2+1$$ where $z$ is a complex number.

Does this have to do with that plane where the "y"-axis is Real numbers and the "x"-axis is Imaginary numbers? I typed it into this complex grapher http://davidbau.com/conformal/#z%5E2%2B1 and I am utterly confused. What's with all the colors? What's with that weird 8 shape?

Comment: Not sure why I have a downvote. I'm just asking about the complex plane. How rude.

Comment: Three question marks in a row is an automatic downvote for me. Terrible formatting.

Comment: @5xum OK? That makes no sense. That's just rude.It's not terrible formatting. There's nothing wrong with adding more question marks. I'm pretty sure there are many other questions with multiple question marks

Comment: Visualizing complex functions is not so simple: we have two dimensions in the domain and two dimensions in the range, which is four dimensions. This is one more spatial dimension than we have to work with in the real world. So we have to pull some kind of trick, which is often to use color. That said, to understand what you're seeing, it would be best to learn about the polar form of a complex number. (The weird 8 shape is caused by the fact that going *halfway* around a circle in the domain sends you all the way around the circle in the range. This is very easy to see using the polar form.)

Comment: @Sam Multiple question marks, to me, are like all-caps writing. I feel like you are shouting. And that's rude.

Comment: @5xum I agree with OP. That shouldn't be the basis for a downvote.

Comment: @Ian What I'm mainly confused about in that function is the output. So let's say I plug in a complex number $f(i+1)$ and I get $2i+1$. What do you do with that $2i+1$?

Comment: What do you mean "do with it"? How do you use it to make a plot? That depends on how you decide to do the projection from four dimensions to three dimensions. Most commonly this projection uses the polar form of the output (using color to show the argument and something else to show the modulus).

Comment: I can't look at that link because it doesn't work on mobile, but sometimes what people do is assign a color to each complex number. To graph the fact that $f(i+1)=2i+1$, we look for the point $i+1$ on the complex plane, and color it with the color corresponding to $2i+1$. If this is the case, graphing $f(z)=z$ should tell you what color is assigned to each point.

Comment: If you mouse over in the top left of the tool in the link, you can read a little bit about the convention that they are using to draw their plots. For instance, the gray 8 in the graph of $z^2+1$ represents the points in the domain which are mapped to the unit circle in the range. These are the unit circles centered at $i$ and at $-i$.

Answer (score 1):

One way to imagine a map $f : D \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with $D \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is to think of it as a 2-dimensional vector field.
Remember that $\mathbb{C}$ is just the vector space $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ equipped with a special multiplication

$$ * : \ \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 $$
$$(v_1,v_2)*(w_1,w_2) = (v_1w_1-v_2w_2,v_1w_2+v_2w_1)$$

that makes $(\mathbb{R}^2,+,*)$ a field. The imaginary unit $i$ is not some magical object, but just a notational symbol to simplifly the practical use of the above multiplication.
Therefore $f$ just maps a set $D\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ into the $\mathbb{R}^2$. For every vector $v \in D$ you can visualize $f$ by mentally attaching $f(v)$ to $v$. If you would plot this, you would get a cohort of arrows in the plane, all starting somewhere in $D$.

Comment: Just to make this a little more concrete, here's a vector plot of the mapping from the question:  [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=StreamPlot%5B%7BRe%5B%28x+%2B+I+y%29%5E2+%2B+1%5D%2C+Im%5B%28x+%2B+I+y%29%5E2+%2B+1%5D%7D%2C+%7Bx%2C+-1000%2C+1000%7D%2C+%7By%2C+-1000%2C+1000%7D%5D)

Answer (score 1):

I like @Joker123's suggestion of visualizing complex maps as vector fields, but I want to point out that this is *not* what is done in the tool you linked at davidbau.com.

The plot at davidbau.com is drawing the preimage of a flat grid and unit circle under the input map.  If you try the identity map ($z$), you'll see that flat grid and unit circle.  If you try a translation (e.g. $z+1$) you'll see that the grid is still composed of straight lines, but the circle in the middle has been shifted.  Note that for $z\to z+1$ the circle is shifted to the *left* not the *right* because this is a preimage.

If you mapped the points of the big grey figure eight in your plot by $z\to z^2+1$ they would form the unit circle.  Similarly, if you applied $z\to z^2+1$ to all the points in the curved grid of your plot, the result would be the same flat grid that's drawn for the identity map.

These sorts of plots are frequently used to visualize [conformal maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_map).

Comment: The gray figure 8 shape is actually the *preimage* of the unit circle under $z^2+1$. This is maybe not so obvious with $z^2+1$, but it is very easy to see with $e^z$, where you get a gray line on the imaginary axis.

Comment: @Ian Oh you're right, and it's easy to see with translations and scales too:  $z + 1$ moves the circle to the left and $z - 1$ moves the circle to the right.  $z/2$ makes the circle (and grid) larger while $2z$ makes them smaller.

Answer (score 1):

In complex functions, every complex number in $\mathbb{C}$ is assigned another number in $\mathbb{C}$. The resulting curve cannot be represented in a 2D or 3D plot, since both domain and image have two real dimensions.

One way around that is to use colors. In the polar representation of $f(z)$
$$
f(z) = r \exp(i \phi)
$$
associate "brightness" with the absolute value of $r$ of $f(z)$ and "hue" with the argument $\phi$. This idea is called [domain coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_coloring).

I recently wrote [cplot](https://github.com/nschloe/cplot), a Python library for domain coloring, which should hopefully make creating and understanding such plots easier. For your function:

```
import cplot

plt = cplot.plot(lambda z: z ** 2 + 1, (-2.0, 2.0, 400), (-2.0, 2.0,400))
plt.savefig("out.png", bbox_inches="tight")
plt.show()
```

[image]

The dark areas are zeros of your function ($\pm i$, makes sense).